# How to suspend an ahk script when another programm (eg. Microsoft Edge) is open?

Tags: autohotkey

Im a noob at coding so pls bear with me. So what I want is to be able to quickly search selected text in chrome, unless Microsoft Edge browser is open, in which case the script should be suspended. Also if the script is suspended ^+e should really go through as  Cntrl + Shift + E as it normally would. This is how far I got:

```
^+e:: 
Send, ^c
Sleep, 100
Run, www.google.com
Sleep, 100
Send, ^v
Send, {Enter}
Sleep, 300
Send, ^v
Send, {Enter}
Sleep, 300
Send, ^v
Send, {Enter}
Sleep, 300
Send, ^v
Send, {Enter}
Sleep, 300
Send, ^v
Send, {Enter}
Sleep, 300
Send, ^v
Send, {Enter}
return


IfWinActive,  Microsoft Edge
  {
     Suspend, on
  }
  else
  {
     Suspend, off
  }
return
```

Im really unsure about the IfwinActive line. Thx for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context sensitive hotkeys are made for this.
For this specific case, the `#IfWinNotActive`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm)</sup> directive is good.
With it you can mark the desired hotkeys to not under some specific window(s).

```
#IfWinNotActive, ahk_exe msedge.exe ;start context sensitive hotkeys
^+e::
    MsgBox, % "Do something"
    ;...
return

+F1::
    MsgBox, % "Do something"
    ;...
return
#IfWinNotActive ;end context sensitive hotkeys
```

Also, I can't really make out what this <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> spam is that you're doing, but to search something, maybe consider just running something like this:

```
TextToSearch := "stackoverflow autohotkey questions"
Run, % "chrome.exe ""https://www.google.com/search?q=" TextToSearch """"
```

You can access the system clipboard from `Clipboard`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Clipboard.htm)</sup>.

Comment: But the command is still executed when Microsoft Edge is open when i put the code like this: ```^+e:: 
Send, ^c
Sleep, 50
Run, www.google.com
Sleep, 100
Send, ^v
Send, {Enter}
Sleep, 300
Send, ^v
Send, {Enter}
Sleep, 300
Send, ^v
Send, {Enter}
Sleep, 300
Send, ^v
Send, {Enter}
Sleep, 300
Send, ^v
Send, {Enter}
return


#IfWinNotActive, ahk_exe ahk_exe   msedge.exe 
^+e::
    MsgBox, % "Do something"

return

+F1::
    MsgBox, % "Do something"


#IfWinNotActive
 ```

Comment: @LeonFasser `#IfWinNotActive` only affects code after the line it is on. Also, for future reference, please use a pastebin for dumping long, multiline code in a comment.